# How to target custom directive with HostBinding to pass success or error message and display it?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm trying to use a custom **directive** in order to show a specific server message/errors after http request.

e.g. in **response** or **error** part, I would like to target the custom directive and throw the highlighted message. The directive should be already embedded in the **component** but not visible. First after passing the server message and displaying it, it should be then shown with a green or red background color, depending on success or failure.

**server-error.directive**:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, Renderer2, HostListener, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
    selector: '[appServerError]'
})

export class ServerErrorDirective implements OnInit {

    constructor( private _elementRef: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer2 ) {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    @HostBinding( 'style.backgroundColor' ) backgroundColor: String = 'red';

}
```

**delete-member.component.ts** (it's a MatDialog):

```
removeUser() {
    this._crudService.deleteUser( this.selectedUser ).subscribe(res => {
        console.log( `res: ${JSON.stringify(res)}` );
    }, err => {
        console.log( `error: ${err.message}` );
    }) ;
}
```

**edit-member.component** (calls and opens the MatDialog):

```
<mat-content>   
.... 
<div appServerError>Success or Error message should be shown here</div>
....
</mat-content>
```

I don't want to use `#xxxx` and `elementRef.nativeElement` to manipulate the DOM. The idea is to use the custom directive as highlighted wrapper for all server response or errors for different Http Requests.

Is there any possibility to achieve this dynamically or am I going in the wrong path/concept?

Have  been searching, unfortunately didn't find something similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a message to your directive in relevance to whatever message from your http response / status. You can do so by implementing it with **@Input and @HostBinding**

**1.) Edit your ServerErrorDirective**

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appServerError]'
})
export class ServerErrorDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input() appServerError: string;       // Same name as your directive attribute selector

    @HostBinding() 
    get innerText() {                      // This is equivalent to javascript's innerText - by supplying a value on the attached/selected element.
       return this.appServerError;         // Return the appServerError message from @Input() and set the innerText with it.
    }

    // This will help you check if the given appServerError message has a keyword 'Success/success' on its sentence, it will set a background color 'green' otherwise 'red' 
    @HostBinding('style.backgroundColor') 
    get backgroundColor () {
       return this.appServerError.toLocaleLowerCase().includes('success') ? 'green' : 'red';
    }

}
```

**2.) On your EditMemberComponent template, you can use it like this:**

```
<mat-content>   
.... 
<div [appServerError]="'Error message here'"></div>     // OR [appServerError]="errorMessage" if errorMessage is set from your component
.... 
</mat-content>
```

It will then be **equivalent** to: `<div>Error message here</div>`

---

> Had created a StackBlitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-directive-set-value) same scenario for your reference.

[image: Result]

Comment: I'am checking few small things regarding MatDialog and will give this a try.